# How to access var from child function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to get id of elements and want to use it to another child function

```
function example(id) {
    var me = this;
    this.pro = ID
    this.code = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(ID)
        }, 20)
    }
    this.validate = function () {
        $('.' + id).keyup(function (e) {
            var ID = this.id;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) me.code()
        })
    }
}
```

### Body

```
<input type="text" class="test" id="1" />
<input type="text" class="test1" id="2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = new example('test')
    var test1 = new example('test1')
    test.validate()
    test1.validate()
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `ID` defined?

Comment: You cannot access the variable before it is defined. You have to define it first, then use it in your functions

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I see it in `this.validate = function () {}`

Comment: @Spokey I mean the other `ID` that is not defined in this snippet.

Comment: @Spokey: Can we access that defining it as a object property

Comment: @amit are you trying to access a variable before it is defined? That really doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `pro` property

```
function example(id) {
    var me = this;
    this.pro = null;
    this.code = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(me.pro);
        }, 20);
    };
    this.validate = function () {
        $('.' + id).keyup(function (e) {
            me.pro = this.id;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) me.code();
        });
    };
}
```

or make it a parameter of that function:

```
function example(id) {
    var me = this;
    this.code = function (ID) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(ID);
        }, 20);
    };
    this.validate = function () {
        $('.' + id).keyup(function (e) {
            var ID = this.id;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) me.code(ID);
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the id of the current element then playing aroung him.

```
function example(id) {
    var currentId = $('.'+id).attr('id');
    this.validate = function () {
        $('.'+id).keyup(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(currentId);
          }  
        });
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = new example('test');
    var test1 = new example('test1');
    test.validate();
    test1.validate();
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ebifuj/3/edit

Comment: That's a class selector, so you can't speak of "current element" when you might have a collection.